# Remarks on a Previous Post: Elementary proof of $n>\frac{p_n}{\ln p_n}$

Tags: number-theory, inequality, prime-numbers

Recently I have been reading [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/835699/fake-proof-of-prime-number-theorem) and I have noted something significant in the fake argument. As  one can easily see that the basic idea behind the argument had been to show that the sequence $x_n=\dfrac{\pi(n)\ln n}{n}$ is strictly decreasing for all $n$.

But, notice that the [Prime Number Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem) is equivalent to the statement that $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty}\dfrac{n\ln p_n}{p_n}=1$. So, the argument of the post previously mentioned can be used to actually prove the Prime Number Theorem if it can be shown that $n>\dfrac{p_n}{\ln p_n}$ for all sufficiently large $n$.

So, is there any elementary method to prove this?

**Edit**:- Yesterday while searching the internet, I have found that  [this paper](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ijm/1255631807) gives a proof of the result (see page 81). But since I am not an expert in this field, I am a bit skeptic about the method of proof. Is there any subtle assumption in the argument that uses PNT?

Comment: Isn't it known that the PNT approximation oscillates between an over- and an under-estimate infinitely many times as $n$ grows?

Comment: @HTFB You are thinking of Littlewood's phenomenon.  No, that's for the much more precise approximation $Li(x)$.  The approximation $\pi(x) \approx x/\ln x$ is off by a significant quantity (about $2x/\ln^2 x$) that doesn't change sign infinitely often.

Comment: Thanks, Erick. Number theory is a big hole in my knowledge; it's good to be able to ask stupid questions here.

Comment: You could read https://primes.utm.edu/howmany.html which also has a table of different ways to approximate pi(n) and 1/log(n) happens to be the worst.