# A question on the prime number theorem as presented in the following paper

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

In the section 2. of [this paper](http://homepage.univie.ac.at/dietrich.burde/papers/burde_23_cheby_error.pdf) it is written that,

> ...The prime number theorem ensures that we can choose $B$ as close to $1$ as we want, provided $x_0$ is sufficiently large.

I think that there should be a subtle correction. The prime number theorem implies that there we can take both $A$ and $B$ arbitrarily close to $1$, not only $B$ as has been stated in the paper. Besides I don't think there is any PNT-independent method to prove the inequality $\dfrac{x}{\ln x}<\pi(x)$ for all sufficiently large $x$. Because as I have mentioned in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/985338/remarks-on-a-previous-post#comment2028627_985338) that the paper doesn't seem to prove the desired inequality of the question without using PNT.

Am I wrong somewhere?

Comment: The paper states that we can take $A=1$.  Are you trying to say that "$A$ arbitrarily close to $1$" is an improvement over $A=1$?

Comment: @ErickWong: I say that we can't take $A=1$ without using PNT.

Comment: The paper doesn't say anything to contradict this.  You claim in your question that the paper says only $B$ can be taken arbitrarily close to $1$.  Where does it say this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Prime Number Theorem implies that both A and B can be taken arbitrarily close to 1; moreover, A can be taken as 1. This does not require a correction to the paper because its claims are correct.

Comment: Does that mean that without using PNT we can say that $\dfrac{x}{\ln x}<\pi(x)$ for all sufficiently large $x$?

Comment: @user170039: I'm not saying that, and neither is the paper.

Comment: See the section "Bounds on the prime counting function" of [this page](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CBwQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FPrime_number_theorem&ei=2xFSVJqAJYbAmwWqxoLwAg&usg=AFQjCNERIpGZ7CXjPH9lzcGsonA45I5adA). My confusion was due to this section.

Comment: @user170039: Nothing in that section says that it avoids the use of the Prime Number Theorem.

Comment: Thank you very much for clearing my doubts. Sorry, for the trouble caused.

Comment: @user170039: Glad to help.